# Mercator Didn't work on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system

Got some problem with Mercator in Geoserver, I tried to display [Flight Information Region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_region) that has been stored in my Postgre.

**The result is more likely drawing using Cartesian projection:**
[image]

**I tried redrawing the FIR based on the same data using WorldWind and got the result:**
[image]

Here is the configuration of the Coordinate Reference System (EPSG:4326):
[image]

And I tried with EPSG:900913 (the result same like the first picture):

[image]

Also I tried to change the Native SRS to 900913 but got error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd"><ServiceException code="internalError">
      Rendering process failed
java.io.IOException
null
ERROR: Operation on two geometries with different SRIDs
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

**Is there anything wrong with the configuration?**

Answer (score 2):

Your data is clearly in EPSG:4326 not EPSG:900913 so when you tell GeoServer that it is in 900913 it gets confused and tries to reproject it in to 4326 when that is what you ask for (and hence it ends up in the wrong place).

You need to leave the projection of the datastore in the same projection as the data is actually in and modify the WMS (or WFS) request to be 900913 then GeoServer can correctly reproject the data to be in the right place on the map.